# After checking on various place, program is returning same longitude and latitude in android/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse. Source code is given below :
When I click first button on various places, the result is same. Please help..    Thanks in advance

GPSSurvey Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vinod.gpssurvey"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.vinod.gpssurvey.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.vinod.gpssurvey;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonSend;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Firstbutton);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
             Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
             String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
             //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 400, 1, this);
             Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

             Double lat,lon;
             try {
               lat = location.getLatitude ();
               lon = location.getLongitude ();

               TextView firstLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.FirstLat);
               TextView firstLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.FirstLong);
                firstLat.setText(lat.toString());
                firstLong.setText(lon.toString());

                String Text = "My current location is: " +
                        "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() +
                        "Longitud = " + location.getLongitude();
                        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
             catch (NullPointerException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
        }

    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FirstLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Longitute : " />


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/FirstLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Latitute : " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Firstbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Corner" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SecLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sec Longitute : " />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/SecLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sec Latitute : "  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Firstbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Corner" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ThirdLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Third Longitute : " />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ThirdLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Third Latitute : " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Thirdbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Third Corner" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FourthLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fourth Longitute : " />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/FourthLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fourth Latitute : " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Fourthtbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fourth Corner" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FifthLong"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fifth Longitute : " />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/FifthtLat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fifth Latitute : " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Fifthbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fifth Corner" />




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, @Vinod, how you are checking at various places ? through a real device ?

Comment: I am checking through a real device, SAMSUNG Grand Mobile. I have to get coordinate of a plot. I had gone to each corner of plot and press first corner button. but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getLastKnownLocation` gives you the last location detected, when the LocationProvider (usually GPS or WiFi) was active and has actually detected a location.

Depending on your device, it can take a while (like 1 minute or longer) till the GPS provider delivers the first location. You can see the status of connecting to GPS satellites on the navigation bar (again, depending on the device you use)

If you're indoors it might never receive any locations.

Your code looks ok to me.